# Parse XML generated using C# Classes

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, uwp

I have a big XML file that I want to parse. I visited [here](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) and generated relevent C# code for this.[Not pasting the complete XML as its having around 30+ classes].

```
  /* 
    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    */
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Xml2CSharp
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="M633Header", Namespace="http://aeec.aviation-ia.net/633")]
    public class M633Header {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="timestamp")]
        public string Timestamp { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="versionNumber")]
        public string VersionNumber { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="FlightNumber", Namespace="http://aeec.aviation-ia.net/633")]
    public class FlightNumber {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="CommercialFlightNumber", Namespace="http://aeec.aviation-ia.net/633")]
        public string CommercialFlightNumber { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="airlineIATACode")]
        public string AirlineIATACode { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="number")]
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="FlightIdentification", Namespace="http://aeec.aviation-ia.net/633")]
    public class FlightIdentification {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="FlightIdentifier", Namespace="http://aeec.aviation-ia.net/633")]
        public string FlightIdentifier { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="FlightNumber", Namespace="http://aeec.aviation-ia.net/633")]
        public FlightNumber FlightNumber { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="DepartureAirport", Namespace="http://aeec.aviation-ia.net/633")]
    public class DepartureAirport {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="AirportICAOCode", Namespace="http://aeec.aviation-ia.net/633")]
        public string AirportICAOCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="AirportIATACode", Namespace="http://aeec.aviation-ia.net/633")]
        public string AirportIATACode { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="airportFunction")]
        public string AirportFunction { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="airportName")]
        public string AirportName { get; set; }
    }
```

I am thinking of a way to parse all the data by using a single method if possible.
What I can think of is this

```
private  void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    string XMLFilePath = Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "UTC34.xml");
    //string data = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);

    if(File.Exists(XMLFilePath))
    {

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(XMLFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        TextReader ff = new StreamReader(fs);
        XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Parse(ff.ReadToEnd());
        XmlSerializer ser1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FlightPlan));
        using (var reader = xmldoc.CreateReader())
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FlightPlan));
            FlightPlan someTest = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as FlightPlan;
            // NotSupportedException here (as inner exception)
        }
    }
}
```

The parsing code above might parse all the data of the `FlightPlan` class only and for other classes I need to write methods(mundane task).
Can anyone help me out with any other way to reduce my efforts ?

Comment: T4 Templates would be good for this.

Comment: In what way ? I didnt understand

Comment: If all of the XML classes you want to generate the desrialization method for are in one namespace and assembly, for example, you could iterate over that in your template, generating the code as you go. Another option might be to create an XML file that contains the names of the assembly-qualified types you want to generate the deserialization methods for, along with any other config params (e.g. file names?), and then have your T4 template work with that.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Why not just do [`serializer.Deserialize(fs))`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsh84875(v=vs.110).aspx) ?  `XmlSerializer` has a built-in method to deserialize from a stream after all.  And why are you constructing two identical `XmlSerializer` objects?

Comment: You should ask about the problem you are trying to solve, not your proposed solution.

Comment: @dbc I am sorry , I have to comment that. Can you help me out to Serialize and deserialize using a single method?

Comment: @IInspectable would be great if you help me in this.I am looking for a way to write a single method to serialize and deseiralize all the classes